# Виды библиографического описания

Tags: общие-вопросы, названия

Есть задание. Надо изучить пример (какой именно пример — не важно) библиографического описания и указать его название:

а) в зависимости от структуры описания;

б) в зависимости от вида ресурса;

в) в зависимости от наличия заголовка.

Все понятно, кроме последнего пункта.

Что значит "в зависимости от наличия заголовка"? Какие бывают библиографические описания в зависимости от заголовка?

**P.S. Не знаю, соответствует ли мой вопрос рамкам сайта, если нет — удалю.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ряде случаев библиографическому описанию может предшествовать заголовок. Это может быть имя автора,
наименование организации, обозначение документа (характерно для технико-экономических, нормативных, патентных и т.п. документов) и др.
Составление заголовка регламентируется отдельным ГОСТом - ГОСТ 7.80—2000 «Библиографическая запись. Заголовок. Основные требования и правила составления».

...Во всех остальных случаях заголовок не используется, библиографическое описание начинается с заглавия. А именно:
• если у описываемого документа (публикации, ресурса) четыре автора или больше
• если у описываемого документа (публикации, ресурса) вообще нет автора (например, сборник статей, материалы
конференции и т.п.)

Это документ с сайта eusp.org

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в качестве ответа надо написать имя автора, наименования организации и т.д? В зависимости от того, что содержится в заголовке.

Comment: Я видел этот текст, но до ума не довел.

Comment: https://www.triumph.ru/bibliograficheskoe-opisanie.html  
Здесь приведены правила и примеры библиографического описания книг, сборников, статей, диссертаций, журналов и других изданий, а также электронных ресурсов по состоянию на начало 2020 года.   Примеры помогут Вам в оформлении выходных данных книг и пр. изданий, а также списка используемой литературы.
Правила составления библиографического описания регламентированы ГОСТ Р7.0.100 – 2018 «Библиографическая запись. Библиографическое описание. Общие требования и правила составления».  
Попробуйте все же ознакомиться со стандартами.

Comment: Спасибо. Только мой вопрос в другом.